# Spring Commons and Spring-data-jpa fail when imported together

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm currently working on a Spring boot Backend, it's my task to update all dependencies and make sure it'll run in Java 11.

I encountered an exception and found out that importing Spring data commons with maven solves the missing `pageableCustomizer()` method.

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Latter is the dependency I added to maven.

After adding that, java tells me the following:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.postProcess(JpaRepositoryConfigExtension.java:120)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource.getAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

The method's class, org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:path_to_project/target/name_of_the_jar.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/data/repository/config/RepositoryConfigurationSource.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/path_to_project/target/name_of_the_jar.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource
```

I've found out that data JPA,

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Is dependent on an older version of data commons

```
+ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.7.RELEASE
  +  org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.8.2.RELEASE
    + org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.10.2.RELEASE
```

Which seems to cause the problem.

I already tried to just use one of them and spent the whole day searching for a solution.

I also tried to use the dependencyManagement offered by Spring:

```xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

That pulled the same versions of all the dependencies. (I, of course, removed the version tag in the dependency)

**EDIT**

The dependency:tree requested.

```sh
[INFO] Application:jar:0.0.3
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:1.4.199:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.3.10.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.23.2-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.8.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.10.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.23:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.60:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-client:jar:1.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.7:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-eventbus:jar:0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-infix:jar:0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.archaius:archaius-core:jar:0.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.12.21:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-apache-client4:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.11:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:4.1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.vlsi.compactmap:compactmap:jar:1.2.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.github.andrewoma.dexx:dexx-collections:jar:0.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.eureka:eureka-core:jar:1.9.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:runtime
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-archaius:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-netflix-archaius:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon:jar:2.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-transport:jar:2.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.reactivex:rxnetty-contexts:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty-servo:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.netflix.hystrix:hystrix-core:jar:1.5.18:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxnetty:jar:0.4.9:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-core:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-httpclient:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-commons-util:jar:0.3.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-loadbalancer:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.netflix.netflix-commons:netflix-statistics:jar:0.1.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- io.reactivex:rxjava:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.netflix.ribbon:ribbon-eureka:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.10:compile
[INFO] |     +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] +- org.camunda.bpm.springboot:camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter:jar:3.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.camunda.bpm:camunda-engine-spring:jar:7.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.camunda.bpm:camunda-engine:jar:7.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.camunda.bpm.model:camunda-bpmn-model:jar:7.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.camunda.bpm.model:camunda-xml-model:jar:7.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.camunda.bpm.model:camunda-cmmn-model:jar:7.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.camunda.bpm.dmn:camunda-engine-dmn:jar:7.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.camunda.commons:camunda-commons-utils:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.camunda.bpm.model:camunda-dmn-model:jar:7.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.camunda.bpm.dmn:camunda-engine-feel-api:jar:7.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.camunda.bpm.dmn:camunda-engine-feel-juel:jar:7.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.camunda.commons:camunda-commons-logging:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.camunda.commons:camunda-commons-typed-values:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.uuid:java-uuid-generator:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] +- swagger_spring_Selfmade:jar:0.0.2-20181112140901_9_e91acd7:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] +- oidc_auth_filter_selfmade:jar:0.1.0-20181112140634_8_2e26773:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.22:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:21.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:5.64.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.mail:javax.mail-api:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
[INFO] |     +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:compile (version selected from constraint [1.3.1,2.3])
[INFO] |     |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.nimbusds:lang-tag:jar:1.4.4:compile (version selected from constraint [1.4.3,))
[INFO] |     \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:7.7:compile (version selected from constraint [5.5,))
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz:jar:2.1.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.1.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.15:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:3.0.1u2:provided
[INFO] |  +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:provided
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1:provided
[INFO] +- camunda_persistence_selfmade:jar:0.0.3-20181204140427_54_6d6c73a:compile
[INFO] +- camunda_templates_modeller(Selfmade):jar:0.1.1-20181204132850_11_89ff2f5:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- jaxrs_client(Selfmade):jar:0.1.0-20181112140855_9_da1fd9b:compile
[INFO] +- jaxrs_jersey_client(Selfmade):jar:0.1.0-20181112141745_76_84d9b84:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.29:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:jakarta.inject:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.activation:jakarta.activation:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.29:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:jar:2.29:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.29:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:jar:2.29:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.11:compile
[INFO] \- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:jar:2.29:compile
```

I started another approach:

Removed ALL dependencies and added only those necessary to build the project (unworking for now) this produced the same error message I before solved with spring data commons. This time I can't solve that:

```sh
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.pageableCustomizer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:327)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203)
    at SpringApplication.main(WorkflowEngineSpringBootApplication.java:94)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:409)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:400)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:375)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration.pageableCustomizer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:449)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:438)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:394)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.web.config.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:275)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.getReturnType(OnBeanCondition.java:458)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:445)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

**EDIT 2**

https://pastebin.com/6ikPBSnF

My maven pom.

Comment: According to the release notes Spring Boot 2.1 should already be Java 11 compatible (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.1-Release-Notes#java-11-support). Generally you should stick to the starters provided by Spring Boot.

Comment: True, but the project is much bigger than just spring boot starter. The project, as it is right now, does not work with Java 11 and the newest versions it needs the data-jpa and data-commons.

Comment: There is something wrong in your question snippets. org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.7.RELEASE depends on  org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.1.7.RELEASE (not 1.8.2.RELEASE as you show) . Please post your `dependency:tree`

Comment: @guido I added the requested information but had to change some package names. I also added what I am currently trying to do.

Comment: You will need to share your maven pom - the spring boot starter data jpa pom and spring data commons pom reference the expected dependencies: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.1.7.RELEASE.pom and https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.1.7.RELEASE.pom

Comment: shared the pom. @James

Comment: Thanks for dep:tree, but what I see does not really make sense (it does not match what the spring-data-starter-jpa declares in its pom). Would you try deleting your _<home>/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot_ directory and trying again?

Comment: In the project with the issue it doesn't change a thing.

Making a test project pulling only data jpa it works as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem could be the dependency for [spring-data-releasetrain on the Fowler-SR2](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-releasetrain/Fowler-SR2/spring-data-releasetrain-Fowler-SR2.pom) release train version.

[image]

This release train is a few years old see the [maven pom](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/data/spring-data-releasetrain/Fowler-SR2/spring-data-releasetrain-Fowler-SR2.pom). You'll want to take a look as to why that is included in your pom.

Comment: The versions in your dependency tree match the versions in the Fowler-SR2 release train, but the `stoffel-parent` pom might influence dependencies in other ways I cannot see.

Comment: This is the answer to my question. It now runs on java 11. I added the releasetrain due to an answer I found while googling an error caused by the new java version unknowingly adding a new error while fixing the other. Thanks for that easy solution which I certainly could have found myself but didn't :D